# Sieve of Euler space complexity in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, primes, space-complexity, sieve

I was given 2 different algorithms written in Haskell aimed to generate the first k primes. As the title suggests, they are the Sieve of Eratoshenes and Euler.

I am trying to understand why Euler implementation uses so much memory. What I thought so far is that the number of streams generated explodes quickly saturating the memory but from what I have understood they should be equal to 2k - 1 where k is the index of the prime we want.
So there should be other major problems.

I tried running the code via GHC's Debugger and it shows that much of the memory allocated is from the minus function so I think streams are definitely part of the problem.

Here minus removes from tcs every multiple of p starting from p*p which is coprime to every prime found so far (except p) and finally generates a new stream passed to the next recursive call of eulerSieve.

```
minus :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
minus xs@(x:txs) ys@(y:tys)
  | x < y = x : minus txs ys
  | otherwise = minus txs tys

eulerSieve :: [Int] -> [Int]
eulerSieve cs@(p:tcs) = p:eulerSieve (minus tcs (map (p*) cs))
```

Reading [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Euler.27s_Sieve) I found that the space is bounded by O(k^2) but it doesn't explain why accurately.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This is (probably) unrelated to your question subject, but anyway: please make it a habit to always add type signatures to you top-level bindings. It makes it so much easier to understand what's being talked about.

Comment: @leftaroundabout you are right! I added type signature to both functions

Comment: Why is `ys` not used at all in the second branch `x > y = minus xs txs`? Is that a typo? What does the function `minus` do? (take the set difference of two sorted lists? these things should be specified in the question.)

Comment: @user202729 yes it was a typo. I added a small description of what minus does.